# Is there a way of achieving this draggable effect with jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

is there a way of creating [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-draggable-view-in-a-container) effect using jquery UI?

thanks in advance.

Comment: please describe your question detailed enough so that it also makes sense once the link breaks.

Comment: also, have a look here. [jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you use firebug and inspect the element, you will see that there is a draggable div inside another div which has overflow: hidden property.

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="draggable" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></div>
</div>

$("#draggable").draggable();
```

This is the concept.

Comment: looks like it should work. is it tested?

Comment: @kritzikratzi no, i haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: this only works to a certain extent: you can drag the image, but it goes outside of the containment div.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `containment` option of jQuery UI Draggable.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AZwbP/

Comment: exactly what I wanted, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It can't be implemented with jQuery draggable. Becuase, here draggable item should not be dragged such that it's top/left point is greater than its container. Same is true for all 4 points.

With jQuery draggable you can't restrict dragging of an element beyond some cordinate.

I suggest to create a custom jQuery plugin with mousedown and mousemove events usages.